# Рисование небольших примитивов DirectX 9

Tags: c++, directx

Есть ли способ эффективно рисовать небольшие примитивы в DirectX? У меня есть главный цикл, и видеокарта нагружается на 30% при отображении линий, но если поместить сцену в цикл (рисовать сразу большое количество вершин), то нагрузка незначительна. Как с этим быть?

```cpp
// параметры:
    this->dxParams_.Windowed = TRUE;
    this->dxParams_.BackBufferWidth = this->screenWidth;
    this->dxParams_.BackBufferHeight = this->screenHeight;
    this->dxParams_.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
    this->dxParams_.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    this->dxParams_.MultiSampleQuality = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
    this->dxParams_.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;
    this->dxParams_.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    this->dxParams_.hDeviceWindow = this->getOverlayHwnd();

    this->dxParams_.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
```

```cpp
// отрисовка:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // данный цикл-обёртка сильно снижает нагрузку
    dxDevice_->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, 0, 1.0f, 0);
    dxDevice_->BeginScene();
    draw();
    dxDevice_->EndScene();
}
dxDevice_->PresentEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

```cpp
// флаги окна:
WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_LAYERED
```

Comment: Какая частота кадров и какая нагрузка процессора при этом?

Comment: andreymal, если рисовать без дополнительного цикла в while true, то частота кадров около 100, нагрузки на процессор почти нет, видеокарта 30% и более. Если сцену обернуть дополнительным циклом, например, на 10 итераций, то частота кадров поднимается до 700, а нагрузка на видекарту сильно падает

Comment: В вопросе не содержится никакой информации, на основе которой можно было бы дать хоть какой-то ответ. Ну а DirectX9 уже устарел.

Comment: user7860670, я добавил дополнительную информацию

Comment: Ну теперь все равно мало что можно сказать, разве что цикл полностью бесполезен, так как в нем по факту может использоваться только результат последней итерации, а может и вообще не рабочий так как Clear вызывается не во время рисования, а результаты вызовов игнорируются.

Comment: user7860670, оптимизации полностью отключены, цикл не бесполезен и Clear работает. Я дошёл к этому циклу методом научного тыка и понял, что он действительно повышает производительность. Я не могу понять почему так и как сделать без этого цикла. Мне кажется, что чем больше вершин, тем производительнее проявляет себя видеокарта